# Как отключить debug в socket.io-client React Native

Tags: отладка, react-native

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую в приложении плагин [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)

Все работает, единственное, что не могу убрать - это вывод debug. Уже все испробовал.

Пробовал вставить в App.js такой код

```
debugModule.disable('engine.io-client:socket');
```

Но когда перегружаешь приложения - все начинает снова выводится